# Get colorpicker input value and use it for url query?

Tags: php, jquery, input, color-picker

I have a jQuery colorpicker that the visitor can change and I am trying to figure out, how can I pass whatever value they enter / pick so that I can use it as a url query?

With what I have right now, you can click the color wheel to get a hex code in the input (such as `#ffffff`) or you can just type it into the input, but what I need to do is then take this value and make a link that links to the website's url plus `?color=#ffffff`.  I can just make a link next to the color picker to do this but I don't know how I can have it link to whatever the visitor chose in the color input.

Here is the live site: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/

Here is the html for the input:

```
<input type="text" name="color-demo" id="color-demo" value="#ff0000" class="colorfield regular-text" data-hex="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can show you your value

```
alert(document.getElementById('color-demo').value);
```

So just add it to your link:

```
<a href="" id="mylink">LINK</a>
```

like this:

```
document.getElementById('mylink').href += document.getElementById('color-demo').value;
```

the JS code above should be invoked when onChange for color-demo fires. For example, change:

```
<input id="color-demo" class="colorfield regular-text" type="text" data-hex="true" value="#ff0000" name="color-demo">
```

to

```
<input id="color-demo" class="colorfield regular-text" type="text" data-hex="true" value="#ff0000" name="color-demo" onChange="myfun()">
```

and create myfun():

```
function myfun()
{
document.getElementById('mylink').href += document.getElementById('color-demo').value;
}
```

Comment: I probably didn't understand this right, but here is what I added.  To the head I added                "<script type="text/javascript">
function myfun()
{
document.getElementById('mylink').href += document.getElementById('color-demo').value;
}
</script>"  Then I changed the input and added the link so it is: "<input type="text" name="color-demo" id="color-demo" value="#ff0000" class="colorfield regular-text" data-hex="true" onChange="myfun()"/><a href="http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/" id="mylink">LINK</a>"

Comment: As you can see- when you change text in your color field it changes the link's address to something like: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/#ff0001 so please change myfun() to something like this: 
document.getElementById('mylink').href += '?color=' +  document.getElementById('color-demo').value;
this will make a nicer link- to index.php. Then you need to handle the new color in index.php script

Comment: When I change the color in firefox the link that I am getting looks like this: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/#fffffc#fffffc#fefffc#fefffc#f8fff8#f8fff8#f0fff4#f0fff4#e4fff3#e4fff3#e0fff7#e0fff7#dcfffc#dcfffc#d4ffff#d4ffff#d0fcff#d0fcff#ccf8ff#ccf8ff#ccf6ff#ccf6ff#c8f6ff#c8f6ff#c4f5ff#c4f5ff#c0f4ff#c0f4ff#bcf3ff#bcf3ff#b8f3ff#b8f3ff#acf6ff#acf6ff#a8f5ff#a8f5ff#9cf7ff#9cf7ff#88f5ff#88f5ff#80ffff#80ffff#78ffff#78ffff#74ffff#74ffff#70ffff#70ffff#6cffff#6cffff#68ffff#68ffff#00fb96#00fb96#00ef9e#00ef9e#00e3a4#00e3a4#00e3ab#00e3ab#00dfa8#00dfa8#00dbb3#00dbb3#00dbba#00c4d7

Comment: I thought you want to change color just once. So please use this: document.getElementById('mylink').href = '?color=' + document.getElementById('color-demo').value;      there is no + before = .